# How can I stop IE from treating URLs as Bing searches?

Tags: internet-explorer, bing

My org requires me to use Internet Explorer for our primary browser. A few times a day, when I key in a URL into the address line in IE (currently using v.11) it gets treated as a Bing search term, even when it is a correctly formatted URL, e.g. "http://www.example.com"

This unwanted behavior occurs under seemingly random circumstances. Is there a way to get IE to treat URLs as URLs and not Bing searches?

Comment: Go talk to the IT department and tell them to install something better, like FireFox or Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a checkbox in the add-ons in Internet Explorer that determines if you search directly from the address bar or not.

From Internet Explorer 11: Click the gear in the top right - then internet options - programs - and Manage Add-ons.

Then, click on Search Providers. At the bottom of the window you should see "Search in the Address bar and the search box on the new tab page." Uncheck this if it is checked.